# sed language translation script - improving efficiency for long texts

Tags: sed

Here's my issue. I'm a Spanish translator, and I have a very lengthy Spanish-English glossary file -- 50K entries. Additionally, I have a stop-word glossary of over 1K entries. I want to strip these entries from texts I plan to translate. So, I built a sed script that, in turn, builds two more sed scripts from the glossaries, which do the stripping, and leave me with only the untranslated text (so I don't have to solve the same problem twice). This works well, but the problem is that it takes a really long time on long texts, sometimes upwards of 15 minutes. Is this simply inevitable, or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Here's the main script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
before="$(date +%s)"

#wordstxt=$(wc -w < $1)
#mintime=$(expr "$wordstxt / 200" |bc -l)
#maxtime=$(expr "$wordstxt / 175" |bc -l)
#echo "Estimated time to process: between $mintime and $maxtime seconds."
sed '
s/\,/\n/g           # strip all commas
s/\?/\n/g       # strip question marks
s/\*/\n/g       # strip asterisks
s/\!/\n/g           # strip exclamation marks
s/:/\n/g            # strip colons
s/\-/\n/g           # strip hyphens
s/\./\n/g           # strip periods
s/«/\n/g            # strip left Euro-quotes
s/»/\n/g            # strip right Euro-quotes
s/”/\n/g            # strip slanted US quotes
s/\"/\n/g       # strip left quotes
s/(/\n/g            # strip left paren
s/)/\n/g            # strip right paren
s/\[/\n/g           # strip left bracket
s/\]/\n/g           # strip right bracket
s/¿/\n/g            # "¿"
s/—/\n/g        # m-dash
s/\ –\ /\n/g        # n-dash
s/…/\n/g        # strip elipsis as a single character, not three periods
s/;/\n/g            # strip semicolon
s/[0-9]/\n/g        # strip out all numbers, replace with returns
' $1 > $1.z.tmp
#echo "Punctuation eliminated."

#cp ../../Spanish\ to\ English\ projects/glossary/stoplist.txt .
sed '
s/^\ //g        # strip leading spaces
s/\ $//         # strip trailing spaces
/^$/d           # delete blank lines
s/\./\n/g       # strip periods
s/\ /\\ /g      # make spaces into literals
s/^/s\//        # begins the substitution
s/$/\/\\n\/g/   # concludes the substitution

1 s/^/#!\ \/bin\/sed\ \-f\n\ns\/\[0\-9\]\/\/g\ns\/\\\ \\\ \/\\\ \/g\ns\/\\\.\\\ \/\\n\/g\n\n/

' stoplist.txt > stoplist.sed
chmod +x stoplist.sed
echo "Eliminating stopwords."
./stoplist.sed $1.z.tmp > $1.0.tmp

sed 's/\([A-Za-z\ ]*\t\).*/\1/' SpanishGlossary.utf8 > tempgloss.2.txt
#echo "Target phrases stripped."

sort -u tempgloss.2.txt > tempgloss.3.txt

awk '{ print length(), $0 | "sort -rn" }' tempgloss.3.txt > tempgloss.4.txt
#echo "List ordered by length."

#echo "Now creating new sed script." # THIS AFFECTS THE SED SCRIPT, NOT THE OUTPUT FILE.

sed '
s/[0-9]//g      # strip out all numbers
s/^\ //g        # strip leading spaces -- all lines have them due to the sort
/^$/d           # delete blank lines
s/\//\\\//g     # make text slashes into literals
s/"/\n/g            # strip quotes
s/\t//g         # strip tabs
s/\./\n/g       # strip periods
s/'\''/\\'\''/g     # make straight apostrophes into literals
s/'\’'/\\'\’'/g     # make curly apostrophes into literals
s/\ /\\ /g      # make spaces into literals
/^.\{0,5\}$/d       # delete lines with less than five characters
s/^/s\/\\b/     # begins the substitution
s/$/\\b\/\\n\/g/    # concludes the substitution

1 s/^/#!\ \/bin\/sed\ \-f\n\ns\/\[0\-9\]\/\/g\ns\/\\\ \\\ \/\\\ \/g\ns\/\\\.\\\ \/\\n\/g\n\n/

' tempgloss.4.txt > glossy.sed

#echo "glossy.sed created."
chmod +x glossy.sed

echo "Eliminating existing entries. This may take a while."
./glossy.sed $1.0.tmp > $1.1.tmp

echo "Now cleaning up lines."
sed -e '
s/\ $//         # strip trailing spaces
s/^\ *//g       # strip any and all leading spaces
s/\ el$//g      # strip "el" from the end
s/\ la$//g      # strip "la" from the end
s/\ los//g      # strip "los" from the end
s/\ las//g      # strip "las" from the end
s/\ o$//g       # strip "o" from the end
s/\ y$//g       # strip "y" from the end
s/\ $//         # strip trailing spaces (yes, again)
' $1.1.tmp > $1.2.tmp

echo "Creating ngrams."
./ngrams 5 < $1.2.tmp > $1.3.tmp 2> /dev/null

linecount="$(wc -l < $1.3.tmp)"
#echo $linecount "lines."
if [ "$linecount" -gt "1000" ]
then
    echo "Eliminating single instances."
    sed '/^1\t/d' $1.3.tmp > $1.4.tmp
else
    echo "Fewer than 1000 entries, so keeping all."
    cp $1.3.tmp $1.4.tmp
fi

sed -e '
s/[0-9]//g      # strip out all numbers
s/^\t//g            # strip leading tab
s/^\ *//g       # strip any and all leading spaces
/^.\{0,7\}$/d       # delete lines with less than six characters
s/\ $//         # strip trailing spaces (yes, again)
#s/$/\t/            # add in the tab
' $1.4.tmp > $1.csv

echo "Looking for duplicates."
sh ./dedupe $1.csv

wordstxt=$(wc -w < $1)
#echo $wordstxt
wordslist=$(wc -w < $1.csv)
#echo $wordslist
wordspercent=$(echo "scale=4; $wordslist / $wordstxt" |bc -l)
wordspercentage=$(echo "$wordspercent * 100" |bc -l)


after="$(date +%s)"
elapsed_seconds="$(expr $after - $before)"
rate=$(echo "scale=3; $wordstxt / $elapsed_seconds" |bc -l)
echo "Created "$1.csv", with $wordspercentage% left, in" $elapsed_seconds "seconds." #, for an effective rate of" $rate "words per second."

rm tempgloss.*.txt
rm *.tmp
rm glossy.sed
```

Comment: Interesting problem, but I won't have time to rewrite your script. Others probably will. You can combine word substitutions like `s/\ el$|\ los|\ la$//`. Using '/g' for strings that contain end-of-line marker `$` may not cost extra time, but makes it harder for someone else to understand your code. You can also sub for many single chars at a time, like `s/[,?\*!:-\.]/\n/g` but using `[ character-class ]` ranges can be confusing. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Even since I posted this, I pulled the punctuation out of the top of the script, and put it in the stopword list. Is there any advantage to the combination you talk about? Would it make sense to have one uber-colossal line, as opposed to thousands of small ones?

Comment: Yes, each scan of a line costs you x time. Using a reg ex that contains, for example, 5 ORed together expressions (using `|`), will cut the time to ~x/5 time. I wouldn't try to cram every possible word on on `s/wd1|wd2/` line, you'll reach a  point of diminishing returns on the time it takes to debug sed error message. Make it so the substitutions group words that are related, so your code will be easier to maintain. There are probably other tricks to include to reduce your overall runtime. Sometimes, the more commands in a pipeline, the better, but can't say right now.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the script in awk and it will run in seconds instead of minutes and be briefer, simpler and clearer. sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line. For anything else, just use awk.

Comment: I really like this idea, but I'm unable to figure out how to apply awk to prose. I'm going to ask this as a separate question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine many of these, for perhaps more speed

```sh
s/[\,\?\*\!:\-\.]/\n/g
```